# How to 'import' a Vue component into a Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

This may be a really silly question, but nonetheless, something I can't find an answer to.

So, I am building up a Vue component and would like to access [vue-spinner](https://github.com/greyby/vue-spinner)'s component(s) inside of my component. How would I do that?

Here are snippets of the code in question:

*app.js*:

```
Vue.component('players', require('./components/TeamPlayersComponent.vue'));

import GridLoader from 'vue-spinner/src/GridLoader.vue';

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        GridLoader
    }
});
```

*TeamPlayersComponent.vue*:

```
<grid-loader></grid-loader>
```

Assume that vue-spinner has been installed (NPM) and that the `TeamPlayersComponent.vue` is valid and working other than giving this error in the console:

`vue.js?3de6:525 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <grid-loader> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option. 
(found in component <players> at /home/vagrant/code/rounds-smaa/resources/assets/js/components/TeamPlayersComponent.vue)`

I am using Vue with Laravel Elixir and Gulp.

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggested methods in the [documentation](https://github.com/greyby/vue-spinner#npm). Please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: Question updated, thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get it by following:

```
var PulseLoader = require('vue-spinner/src/PulseLoader.vue');
```

and add it in components:

```
new Vue({
  components: {
    'PulseLoader': PulseLoader
  }
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Solution:

Replace the `GridLoader` specific code in app.js (Laravel setup) with:

`Vue.component('grid-loader', require('vue-spinner/src/GridLoader.vue'));`

Worked as expected!

Answer (score 3):

I think that you should register the component locally in TeamPlayersComponent.vue file. Import the component and register in the file.

```
    import gridLoader from 'vue-spinner/src/GridLoader.vue'
```

Then register the component locally.

```
    components: {
                gridLoader
               }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also import as follows:

```
import grid-loader from "vue-spinner/src/GridLoader.vue";
```

and then in then in the component where you want to import it:

```
components: { grid-loaderfrom }
```